# integrate the facebook,twitter and social networking site on .net website?

Tags: javascript, .net

i have facebook AND twitter iamge on my site.and onclick these image,how to redirect at facebook and twitter login page.

Answer (score 0):

**Twitter**

```
<a href="www.twitter.com" target="_blank">
<img style="border:0;" src="twitter image" alt="Twitter" >
</a>
```

**Facebook**

```
<a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
<img style="border:0;" src="facebook image" alt="Facebook" >
</a>
```